# In Swift 2, what is the proper way to disable a NSMenuItem?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2, nsmenuitem

There is a public enabled property but setting it to false has no effect.

```
startItem.enabled = false
```

My current solution is to set action's Selector to empty string.

```
var startItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Start", action: Selector(""), keyEquivalent: "")
```

This feels unintuitive as to why you can set enabled to false but not have an effect.

Comment: are you kidding...you just posted a question and within sec you posted an answer...the best would be to delete the question

Comment: There is a checkbox for "Answer your own question". Also, I didn't accept my own answer because I don't know if it is the proper way. I had difficulty with this question. Google gave me Objective C, cocao answers from 2004 and "My item is disabled when I didn't expect it to be".

The question also hasn't been asked before. I think there is a better way using validateuserinterfaceitem.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: What really happened was I spent a couple of hours looking up how to do this. I overlooked "set autoenablesItems to false' because I tried "startItem.autoenablesItems = false". Then when I do a post for stack overflow, I like to tell others what I've done and researched. When I retraced my steps, I thought about it more. Now I am 80% done with the post and I decide it would be best to do a knowledge share in a "Q and A' format. I hope this post helps others or if it is indeed poor quality, that the mods remove it. If you feel the later, use the flag button.

Comment: sorry buddy..didn't know about that +1 for your answer :) if its worth to others

Comment: you should accept your answer as per SO guidelines ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
startItem.enabled = false
```

won't work unless you set autoenableItems to false on the parent menu like so:

```
let menu = NSMenu();
menu.autoenablesItems = false
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html